# Google now cards

Tags: html, json-ld, google-now

I have a html script for flight reservation that shows me google now cards in inbox.
But when I am trying to embed JSON-ld script tags into the HTML content to get those tags in google now cards, the cards completely disappear.
Has anyone worked on google now cards before or knows how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please post the code you have, it makes it a lot easier to help.

Comment: I recommend checking out the documentation on Google Schemas for Now cards (https://developers.google.com/schemas/now/cards). Additionally, check out the documentation on registering for Google Schemas (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google?hl=en).