# Google Now cards with JSON-ld

Tags: json-ld, google-now

I am trying to customize my Google now cards by embedding JSON-ld script into my HTML document, but it doesn't work at all.
Is there any prerequisite for using JSON-ld for Google now cards?

Comment: Isn’t this essentially the same like your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875927/google-now-cards

Comment: There is a minor differenece.  Earlier I faced an issue that after embedding JSON-ld, my existing cards were disappearing, but now I can see the cards, the way they should be from my HTML.   I am trying to add tags through JSON-ld, but the tags aren't visible.